# Is there a option to get the event grid trigger url + key at output value from the deployment of a Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-eventgrid

Is there a option to get the event grid trigger url + key at output value from the deployment of a Azure Function?

The scenario we would like to do is as followed:
- We deploy a Function Service in a VSTS release via ARM.
- With the Function service deployed we deploy the event grid subscription.

Thanks,
Shraddha Agrawal

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way using the REST API to obtain a function access code. The following are the steps:

1. Let assume a name of the function is *EventGridTrigger2* and the run.csx:

   ```
   #r "Newtonsoft.Json"

   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

   public static void Run(JObject eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
   {
       log.Info(eventGridEvent.ToString(Formatting.Indented));

   }
   ```

and the function.json file:

```
    {
        "bindings": [
        {
          "type": "eventGridTrigger",
          "name": "eventGridEvent",
          "direction": "in"
        }
       ],
       "disabled": false
    }
```

As you can see the above bindings is untyped, which will work for any output schema such as *InputEventSchema*, *EventGridSchema* (default schema) and *CloudEventV01Schema* (after fixing some bug).

2. The *destination* property of the created Subscription looks like the following:

   ```
   "destination": {
       "properties": {
         "endpointUrl": null,
         "endpointBaseUrl": "https://myFunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig"
       },
       "endpointType": "WebHook"
     },
   ```

Note, that the full subscriberUrl for Azure EventGrid trigger has the following format, where the query string contains parameters for routing request to the properly function:

```
https://{FunctionApp}.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={FunctionName}&code={masterKey}
```

For creating a subscriber we have to use its full subscriberUrl included a query string. In this moment, the only unknown value is the masterKey.

3. To obtain a Function App (Host) masterkey we have to use a management REST API call:

   ```
   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mySubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{myResGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{myFunctionApp}/functions/admin/masterkey?api-version=2016-08-01
   ```

the response has the following format:

```
    {
       "masterKey": "*************************************************"
    }
```

Note, that the authentication **Bearer token** is required for this call.

Once we have a masterKey for the FunctionApp (host), we can use it for any function within this host.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking: "how can I deploy an Azure Function with a step in a VSTS Release using ARM and get its trigger url so that I can use the trigger url in the next VSTS Release step?"

It's not very well documented, but using the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#list), [this blog post](https://blog.mexia.com.au/list-of-access-keys-from-output-values-after-arm-template-deployment#functions) and some trial and error, we've figured out how.

This is what the ARM should look like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {}
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "triggerUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listsecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', 'functionAppName', 'functionName'),'2015-08-01').trigger_url]"
    }
  }
}
```

You deploy it with an "Azure Resource Group Deployment" step, make sure that you enter a variable name in the "Deployment outputs" text box, let say `triggerUrl`.

Example output:

```
{"triggerUrl":{"type":"String","value":"https://functionAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/functionName?code=1234"}}
```

Then you put a PowerShell step (or an Azure PowerShell step) afterwards that picks up the value from the variable.

```
$environmentVariableName = "triggerUrl"
$outputVariables = (Get-Item env:$environmentVariableName).Value
```

Then do something with it.

Comment: I think, the question is related to the event grid subscription with a webhook event handler for the EventGridTrigger function. For this integration, the trigger_url obtained by /listsecrets is not suitable endpoint, it must be preprocessed such as validation, etc. and then forwarded to the function. From the event subscription point of the view, the trigger_url can be used only for HttpTrigger function, but in this case, the httptrigger function has a responsibility for handling a message validation.

Answer (score 0):

With update of Functions App [V2.0.12050](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129) the URI of the Event-Grid trigger is a little different. See also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid)