# Possible to get an Azure Function systemkey in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-eventgrid

I know that I can get the host key and trigger_url of an Azure Function in an ARM template by using the listKeys/listSecrets method.
But I need the systemkey, I'm deploying an Event Grid Subscription and it needs the Azure Function endpoint url which contains the system key:

```
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/StorageAccounts/providers/eventSubscriptions",
            "name": "[concat(concat(parameters('publisherName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/'), parameters('name'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
            "properties": {
                "destination": {
                    "endpointType": "[parameters('endpointType')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "endpointUrl": "[parameters('endpointUrl')]"
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "subjectBeginsWith": "[parameters('subjectBeginsWith')]",
                    "subjectEndsWith": "[parameters('subjectEndsWith')]",
                    "subjectIsCaseSensitive": "[parameters('subjectIsCaseSensitive')]",
                    "includedEventTypes": "[parameters('includedEventTypes')]"
                },
                "labels": "[parameters('labels')]"
            }
        }
    ]
```

where endpointUrl is in the form of:

```
https://<function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName=<function-name>&code=XZvGU0ROPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaieD89gPQ==
```

The parameter named 'code' is the systemkey, which can be retrieved by doing a GET on

```
http://<function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/systemkeys/eventgridextensionconfig_extension?code=<master_key>
```

Is there a way to retrieve this systemkey (or the entire endpointurl) in the ARM template without resorting to bash scripts that inject it or other external systems?

The documentation does say: "However, you cannot use list operations that require values in the request body." So I don't think I'll be able to with a 'list' operation.

Comment: have a look at my answer for creating a full endpointUrl of the EventGridTrigger function subscriber  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367435/is-there-a-option-to-get-the-event-grid-trigger-url-key-at-output-value-from-t

Comment: I actually ran across your answer, but it is a solution using a REST call, so some scripting is needed. I was hoping for a pure ARM based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible right now. You can return only function keys using the ARM template.
Same described here:
https://blog.mexia.com.au/list-of-access-keys-from-output-values-after-arm-template-deployment#functions

Comment: I was afraid so..always those limitations when trying to work with ARM templates :(

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is now possible:

```
"destination": {
    "endpointType": "WebHook",
    "properties": {
        "endpointUrl": "[concat(variables('functionUrl'), listKeys(resourceId(variables('functionResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Web/sites/host/', variables('functionAppName'), 'default'),'2016-08-01').systemkeys.eventgrid_extension)]"
    }
},
```

Where `functionUrl` ends with `&code=`. Tested that on runtime ~2.

Comment: oh that would be great, gonna try it out!

Comment: This only works if the function has been deployed before the template is run. That means it's not likely to work if you want to use a systemkey from another reasource in the same deployment.